# Reduce voltage by a constant 100mV

Tags: adc, dc-dc-converter

For a project I have a digital thermometer which outputs a DC voltage of 100mV at 20 degrees C and 250mV at 50 degrees C, which is the range we're interested in.
We're putting that into an Arduino via and ADC, which can handle voltages of 0-5V.
To make best use of the resolution of the ADC I'd like to reduce that 100mV-250mV to 0 to 5V, but although I can find circuits for the gain easily enough, I can't seem to figure out the initial reduction of 100mV.

Comment: Could also gain it and then reduce it, maybe with a diode or resistors.

Comment: Maybe something like a level shifter? http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4836

Comment: The level shifter looks like pretty much what I'm looking for, thanks very much. I can't see how I'd go about adapting that for the numbers I'd need though?

Comment: It may not be as ideal, but you could just gain it up by 20, then use the range from 2-5V.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do you. The required gain is span out/span in  = 5/0.15 = 33.33, so R1/(R3||R2) = 32.33. If we pick R1 = 100K, then R3||R2 = 3.09K. Pick R3 so that the output voltage is zero with 100mV in (and 5V reference). If your reference is not 5V, then you can recalculate R3 and R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgpBq0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Since this is a temperature measurement, an RC lowpass on the + input would be a VERY good idea.

Comment: What @WhatRoughBeast said.. since the op-amp input is high-Z an R-C is a natural. Also bypass the power supply adequately and make sure the op-amp is R-R output and single supply if it's powered from +5V/0V. This is just a snippet to show the resistor arrangement for offset with a single op-amp.